# How to share a Google Doc on Google Drive using an existing URL?

Tags: google-drive

I have seen that for file types not native to Google Drive there is the option to "manage versions" so that if I have shared the URL for a specific file on my drive with everyone, I can upload a new version and use manage versions to replace the existing file being shared by the eisting URL with my newer file.

What about for native Google Drive files? I have written a Google Docs document, shared it, I made a copy which I hvae been revising and updating, now I want the existing URL I shared with everyone to point to the updated version.

Is this possible, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time that is not possible. One alternative is to do the following:

1. Use two tabs or windows, each one to open the old document and the other to open the new document with the updated content.
2. In the new document copy all the updated content.
3. Go to the old document, select all, then paste the content.

If you change the updated document settings, like page margins or background, you will have to apply them to new document manually.

Comment: It seems you are right and this is not possible, just a side not to others trying this, copy and best using chrome worked much than than Firefox!